# How do I format a long integer as a string without separator in Java?

Tags: java, messageformat

Simple question, but I'll bet that asking on here will probably be more straight forward than trying to understand the documentation for `MessageFormat`:

```
long foo = 12345;
String s = MessageFormat.format("{0}", foo);
```

Observed value is "12,345".

Desired value is "12345".

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Just use [`Long.toString(long foo)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toString-long-)

Comment: String.valueOf() calls Long.toString()

Comment: Maybe this is trifling but in this case you're relying on an undocumented behavior of Long.toString(foo). For that reason, I prefer Daniel Fortunov's answer.

Comment: It's not undocumented. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toString%28long%29.

Comment: Rob H: Oh, you're right, though I'd point at the docs for Long#toString(long, int)

Comment: OK, however this solution is not applicable to message formatting in ResourceBundle. [Tuto i18n](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/messageFormat.html)

Comment: If you are using resource bundles, then Daniel Fortunov's answer is definitely preferable.

Comment: IMO this is a better answer than the accepted one based upon the question. Had the question specified "how do I tell a resource bundle to display a number without separators" then the accepted one would be better.

Answer (score 406):

```
MessageFormat.format("{0,number,#}", foo);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do this with MessageFormat properties injection. Good thing there's more than one way to do it!

Comment: i prefer this way. since it allows me to change the format in my language properties file.

Comment: Nice..!! @daniel-fortunov Can you please explain what and how its done ?

Comment: Perfect solution! Helped me keep the format/unformat option in reference data instead of at code level - thanks! And as @SebastianRoth said - this should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: This doesn't not work for Java8. Locale still intrudes and if your locale has setGroupingUsed==true then you will get grouping symbols injected. Very problematic if you only want certain integers to not have default locale grouping symbols.

Comment: I'm actually surprised why prettying numeric strings a default and not an explicit thing with the formatter API

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you.  I'm using the buildnumber Maven plugin and it kept formatting the build number with a comma, no matter what I put inside the <format> element.

Comment: This works also inside a choice format if you quote the pattern: `MessageFormat.format("{0,choice,0#no foos|1#one foo|1<'{0,number,#}' foos}"`

Comment: @GOTO0 I only just noticed that way back in 2017 you posted this comment. No up-votes so it was hidden to me (hopefully fixed now!). My posted answer basically says the same thing, with a much more elaborate example.

Comment: This works. I searched a lot and got this solution.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this a little bit when trying to do "real world" patterns with internationalization, etc. Specifically, we have a need to use a "choice" format where the output depends upon the values being displayed, and that's what `java.text.ChoiceFormat` is for.

Here is an example for how to get this done:

```
    MessageFormat fmt = new MessageFormat("{0,choice,0#zero!|1#one!|1<{0,number,'#'}|10000<big: {0}}");

    int[] nums = new int[] {
            0,
            1,
            100,
            1000,
            10000,
            100000,
            1000000,
            10000000
    };

    Object[] a = new Object[1];
    for(int num : nums) {
        a[0] = num;
        System.out.println(fmt.format(a));
    }
```

This generates the following output; I hope it's helpful for others who are trying to accomplish the same types of things:

```
zero!
one!
100
1000
10000
big: 100,000
big: 1,000,000
big: 10,000,000
```

As you can see, the "choice" format allows us to choose the type of format to use depending upon the value being passed-in to be formatted. Small numbers can be replaced with text (no display of the original value). Medium-sized numbers are shown with no grouping separators (no commas). The largest numbers do include the commas, again. Obviously, this is an entirely contrived example to demonstrate the flexibility of `java.text.MessageFormat`.

A note about the quoted `#` in the format text: since both `ChoiceFormat` and `MessageFormat` are being used, there is a collision between metacharacters between the two. `ChoiceFormat` uses `#` as a metacharacter that essentially means "equals" so that the formatting engine knows that e.g. in the case of `1#one!` we are comparing `{0}` with `1`, and if they are equal, it uses that particular "choice".

But `#` has another meaning to `MessageFormat`, and that's as a metacharacter which has meaning for `DecimalFormat`: it's a metacharacter which means "put a number here".

Because it's wrapped up in a `ChoiceFormat` string, the `#` needs to be quoted. When `ChoiceFormat` is done parsing the string, those quotes are removed when passing the subformats to `MessageFormat` (and then on to `DecimalFormat`).

So when you are using `{0,choice,...}`, you have to quote those `#` characters, and possibly others.

Comment: Wow kudos for digging this one, and it's been there since Java 1.1 !

Answer (score -1):

The shortest way is

```
long foo = 12345;
String s = ""+foo;
```

Comment: And, as always, this expands to `new StringBuilder("").append(foo).toString()` so it's not really optimal.

Comment: @RAnders00 Converting a number into a single string is unlikely to be the most optimal option, depending on the context you can usually avoid it entirely, but for the simplest pattern you can use `""+`

Comment: You are right, but I just wanted to point it out since people always tend to point it out.

Comment: @RAnders00 btw using a message format is an order of magnitude more expensive, and more complicated in this case.

Comment: Yeah, one should instead use `Long.toString()` since it's what this solution uses in the background anyways :)

Comment: @RAnders00 ... unless you value your developer time more than your CPU time (which is usually the case)

Answer (score -2):

As an alternative `String.format` and `java.util.Formatter` might work for you as well...

Comment: Need a solution for property file, not code wise.

Answer (score -6):

You could try:

```
String s = new Long(foo).toString();
```

Comment: Unnecessary object creation. Never use new with wrapper classes.