# tinylog is formatting ordinary numbers like money

Tags: java, logging, tinylog

I'm using tinylog inside glassfish for logging my web service requests. here is a log statement:

```
Logger.info("record received from user: {0}, stationAxisId: {1}. inserted with recordId: {2}. server timestamp: {3}", username, stationAxisId, res.recordId, res.timeStamp);
```

the problem is `stationAxisId` which is integer. but what I see in the log file is:

```
addNewRecord-INFO-record received from user: kia, stationAxisId: 10,543,201. inserted with recordId: 56. server timestamp: 1391/07/04 13:55:35.348
```

It is formatting `stationAxisIs` like money. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tinylog uses MessageFormat internally, so see second answer to this: [How do I format a long integer as a string without separator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942118/how-do-i-format-a-long-integer-as-a-string-without-separator-in-java)